# Do the “Master Scrivener” and “Magic Item Adept” features stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, wizard, artificer

Does the “Master Scrivener” feature from the Order of Scribes subclass stack with the “Magic Item Adept” feature from the Artificer class when determining the time and gold cost for crafting common and uncommon spell scrolls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### These should stack if the conditions are met

The Artificer's "Magic item adept" 10th level feature contains this text:

> If you craft a magic item with a rarity of common or uncommon, it takes you a quarter of the normal time, and it costs you half as much of the usual gold.

The text specifically states that it costs half as much as the "usual gold" and a quarter of the "normal time". So if a scroll normally took 1000 gold and eight days to create, it would now cost 500 gold and two days.

Now consider the Master Scrivener 10th level feature which contains this text:

> The gold and time you must spend to make such a scroll are halved if you use your Wizardly Quill.

It says nothing about the usual amount of time or gold so it should stack with the other ability. So the scroll, in the above example, will now cost 250 gold and 1 day to create.

Your character will need to meet the conditions of crafting a scroll of common or uncommon rarity and be using their wizardly quill.

Comment: I would have a balance concern about this, except you'd need to be 20th level to even try it, so who even cares at that point? Losing out on the upper level spell slots is a much worse cost than a little extra gold!

Comment: @DarthPseudonym You can only make up to uncommon items anyway which, in spell scroll terms, means only up to level 3 spells. Sure, you could make a hoard of fireball spells and use them to devastate and army for example. But, as you say, it comes at the cost of being a level 20 spell caster who could just drop a meteor swarm.